# Sql request into CSV

Tags: php, sql, csv, export-to-csv

(Sorry about my english, feel free to correct me, French guy here)
I'm trying to put the result of a SQL request into a .csv file, i'd follow some tutorials and online forums instructions and there are my result :

```
<?php
try{
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=baseontpe;charset=utf8', 'root', '',array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
    }
    catch (Exception $e){
        die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
    }

$CP=$_GET['CP'];
$Act=$_GET['Act'];

$req = $bdd->prepare('SELECT Nom, Prenom, EMail FROM b2b WHERE CP LIKE ? AND Activiteft LIKE ?');
$req->execute(array($CP.'%','%'.$Act.'%'));

$handle = fopen('test.csv', 'w');
$req->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while($donnees = $req->fetch()) {
    fputcsv($handle, $donnees, ';');
}
$req->closeCursor();
fclose($handle);

header("Content-Type: text/csv;charset=utf-8");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=test.csv');
?>
```

But my results with this code are not very satisfying... Just a lines like this :

> ÐÏà¡±á                ;  þÿ                          þÿÿÿ   
>   þÿÿÿ       
>   ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿýÿÿÿþÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿR
>   o o t   E n t r y                                              
>   ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ                                   
>   þÿÿÿ                                                                            ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ                                   
>   þÿÿÿ                                                                            ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ                                   
>   þÿÿÿ                                                                            ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ                                    þÿÿÿ

Any advice please ? I'm really stuck right now :(

Comment: Possibly try a different charset?

Comment: well i'm not even sure that the charset is even usefull here, it doesn't change anything when i removed it or put another one

Answer (score 0):

It would be better todo a select in to file method instead?

```
SELECT Nom, Prenom, EMail FROM b2b WHERE CP LIKE ? AND Activiteft LIKE ? INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/b2b.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```